# AutoCAD C# Release .dwl file

Tags: c#, api, autocad

Hello AutoCAD C# Masters,
I have this code down here that opens a drawing, change some layers and close, but after it's done and the drawing closes, there is a file named **DocName.dwl** in the same folder as the dwg that I can't delete without closing autocad.

Is there a place where I can release the lock and I'm not doing?

```
    [CommandMethod("Test", CommandFlags.UsePickSet | CommandFlags.Redraw | CommandFlags.Session | CommandFlags.Modal)]
    public void Test()
    {
        var DocList = AskUserToSelectDocs();
        foreach (string FileName in DocList.Files)
        {
            Application.DocumentManager.Open(FileName, false);
            Document zcDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
            Database zcDB = zcDoc.Database;

            using (DocumentLock acLckDoc = zcDoc.LockDocument())
            {
                using (Transaction ZcTran = zcDoc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
                {
                    BlockTable zcBLT = (BlockTable)ZcTran.GetObject(zcDB.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                    BlockTableRecord zcBLTR = (BlockTableRecord)ZcTran.GetObject(zcBLT[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite);

                    zcBLTR.UpgradeOpen();
                    var editor = zcDoc.Editor;

                    var SelectionSet = editor.SelectAll().Value;

                    foreach (ObjectId Objeto in SelectionSet.GetObjectIds())
                    {
                        Entity ent = ZcTran.GetObject(Objeto, OpenMode.ForWrite) as Entity;
                        if (ent is Viewport)
                        {
                            var VP = ent as Viewport;
                            VP.Layer = "Defpoints";
                        }
                    }

                    editor.Regen();

                    ZcTran.Commit();
                }

            }

            zcDB.SaveAs(zcDB.Filename, zcDB.OriginalFileVersion);
            zcDoc.CloseAndSave(zcDoc.Name);
            zcDoc.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT: Now the full code**

Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted crashes on `zcDB.SaveAs(zcDB.Filename, zcDB.OriginalFileVersion);` because of `eFileSharingViolation`. You can't really do what you're doing with the active document. What is your goal? What are trying to achieve overall? is this for batch processing?

Comment: consider: (a) save the file with a different name, (b) close the file, (c) delete the old file, and (d) rename the new file back to the old name.  Kludgey, but...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, now I did paste all the code, except the part where the user select the drawing, but its only an OpenFileDialog improvement, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, there is no need to open the document. I would suggest just loading the database into memory, manipulating it, then saving. All of this will be outside the 'DocumentManager'. Great for performance, especially as the number of files to process increases.

It does not matter which document is currently open, as long as it is not one of the ones getting processed (you can check for that).

Try this:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var DocList = AskUserToSelectDocs();
    //save working db reference
    Database originalDB = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
    foreach (string FileName in DocList.Files)
    {
        //a little trick here:
        //construct the database in memory, and read in the target file.
        //now your database is your working database, not the active doc!!
        using (Database database = new Database(false, true))
        {
            database.ReadDwgFile(FileName, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite, true, string.Empty);
            HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase = database;//important!
            using (Transaction transaction = database.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                //do your stuff
            }
            //reset WorkingDB to original db
            HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase = originalDB;
            database.SaveAs(FileName, DwgVersion.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for your help, but I've tried to get the objects from the database, with a `transaction.GetAllObjects();` and the enumerator has 0 objects. In my code I use the editor to get the objects, how would you do here?